# Vue JS Filter for Title Case

Tags: vue.js, filter

I am absolutely new to Vue JS so please forgive me if my question sounds dumb.

I am learning to create string filters in Vue JS. I was able to convert my string to uppercase using following code.

```js
var app=new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data:{
        message:'hello world',
    },
    filters:{
        uppercase(value){
            return value.toUpperCase();
        },
    }
})
```

Now I am trying to make a filter to convert my message to Title Case. eg. `hello world` to `Hello World`

I have tried many things like:

```js
filters:{
    upper(value){
        value.toLowerCase().split(' ');
        return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+value.slice(1);
    }
}
```

But I am unable to create a filter correctly. How can we use a for loop inside Vue JS? Or is there any other way to accomplish the Title Case?

Comment: A Vue filter is just a JavaScript function. There's not really anything specific to Vue about how you implement the contents of that function. Have you tried just searching for a JavaScript implementation of converting a string to title case?

Comment: Ahaan. Thanks I ll just try that. :)

Comment: In this particular case, Since your objective to just display the text, it might be better to use [css style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform) for this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
filters: {
    titleize(value){
        return value.replace(/(?:^|\s|-)\S/g, x => x.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

Comment: What if value is uppercase ? example **MYTITLE**

Comment: @FreddyDaniel I posted an example of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64752866/8755524

Answer (score 4):

Filters/ Mappers, can be simple JS `methods` who receives some `param`, apply operation on it and returns a `value`.

I believe you really don't need a JS method for this,

Try to apply the `text-transform` CSS style to `HTML`.

> eg: ( text-transform: capitalize );

```css
h1 { text-transform: capitalize; }
```

```html
<h1>hello world </h1>
```

Use JS approach when absolutely necessary.

Comment: Hey Thanks Satyam. Yea this does the job but I was just curious to try the JS Filter way for learning purposes only. Appreciate the help thou :)

Answer (score 1):

If the value is in uppercase, you can use it this way:

```
Vue.filter("TitleCase", value => {
  return value.toLowerCase().replace(/(?:^|\s|-)\S/g, x => x.toUpperCase());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @skirtle. I used the below code.

```
    filters:{
     upper(str){
       str = str.toLowerCase().split(' ');

       let final = [ ];

        for(let  word of str){
          final.push(word.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+ word.slice(1));
        }

      return final.join(' ')      
        }
      }
```

This worked like a charm. :)